# install attempt of NEW laravel 5.3.xxx (new dist) failed with 255 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

First things first: am running PHP 5.6.10, so composer should execute without any issues.

When attempting to install a new Laravel 5.3.xxx project or simply run composer update, I continuously get the error "Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255"

Several items here:

• The error screen does not indicate what error except what is shown in the above message.

• composer is at the very latest version

• The actual command being run is

**php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel APPNAME** 
(again, the PHP version is above 5.6.4).

I have no idea what's happening here..thoughts?

Comment: What's in your php error log? And what happens when you run `php artisan`?

Comment: run your command with the verbose flag and see if that gives you more information.

Comment: @Johnathan Kuhn: I should have mentioned it in the parent but I have been running composer update with -v and the only message is php /usr/local/bin composer.phar update -v
[.......]
Analyzed 37756 rules to resolve dependencies
Nothing to install or update
Dependency resolution completed in 0.003 seconds
Generating autoload files
> post-update-cmd: Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> post-update-cmd: php artisan optimize
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255.

Comment: @treeface no errors or warnings are thrown in the log. when running php artisan, it beings back the list of commands that can be used.

also, just for grins, I've also tried clearing composer's cache, dumping the cut-load, because at this point I'm just "why not?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running `php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel APPNAME --no-scripts`

This will prevent the scripts from being executed, but still give you a working installation.

Comment: That did it; thank you! Do you have any insight into why the scripts would be failing?

Comment: Not really, it's just been one of those funny things that happens from time to time as far as I know.